# Throwing a LocalVariableDeclarationJava error after changing the linkedlist name

Tags: java

```
package linkedlist;
class SList{
    private SNode head;
        public SNode remove(String s){
        SNode prev;
        SNode curr;
        prev=head;
        curr=head.next;
        while(curr.key!=s && curr.key!=s){
            prev=curr;
            curr.next;
        }
        return ;

    }
    //node set up 
    private class SNode{
        private String key;
        private SNode next;
    }
}
```

On the curr.next Im getting `Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationJava(1610612976)` and it only happened after I changed the package name. If you'd like more information I can post some more.

Comment: The `curr.next;` expression is not a valid Java statement.  This problem was most likely there before you changed the package name, but it *could be* that the problem you were fixing by changing the package name was hiding it.  (If your code is too messed up, the compiler typically can't find all of the problems.)

Comment: The reason for the obscure compilation error is that the compiler is a bit confused.  It "thinks" that you were trying to write a variable declaration at that point, whereas you probably *need* an assignment statement; e.g. `curr = curr.next;`.